# Where did all these posts come from?

Tags: discussion, migration

As part of the process for creating the [Jewish Life & Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning) Stack Exchange, mi.yodeya (an early Stack Exchange 1.0 site) has agreed to provide a jump start to this community by migrating their content to this new platform. All the users and content have been migrated to this site — the questions, answers, comments, voting, badges, reputation; It's all here.

**This Judaism Q&A welcomes all people with questions and answers about Jewish law and tradition.**

The initial content and Google ranking is a windfall to this community. But the only way to build a lively and engaging site is to go through the same community-building process our other sites experience: organizing the site, deciding what type of questions are appropriate here, and [taking ownership of the site governance](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

While, technically speaking, the site already has a lot of content, I would urge you to read this blog post:

[**Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

I hope everyone will stay engaged and become actively involved in building this site. Get involved in your [meta forum](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com) and start asking the essential questions.

This early participation is really, really important. Other communities have been known to skip over the initial community-building activities after they received imported data… [**and they are still struggling for it**](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/462/my-concerns-about-onstartups-after-10-days/464#464). It's a crucial part of the community-building process. The earliest activities and questions will set the tone and topic of the site for a long time.