# Why can't I edit posts on meta?

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, privileges

I have the required 500 rep on the main site so that I can edit posts, but why don't I see the edit link here on meta?

Main page screenshot:
[image: main j.se]

Meta page screenshot:
[image: meta j.se]

Comment: why close?......

Comment: @ShmuelBrill want to move to main meta.se. I also flagged it,

Comment: Tagging [meta-tag:status-bydesign] in light of the answers, which are AFAICT correct.

Comment: @msh210 please don't tag as such until you are 100%. On this area I do not think you have the knowledge to know these things. I am trying to flesh it out with Sathya.

Comment: @msh210 see comments on http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/926/719

Answer (score 7):

The reputation levels for privileges here on Judaism aren't currently at the same levels as [other public beta sites](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), due to an oversight during the [migration from the original mi.yodeya site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from).

As the site approaches [its graduation](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/design-for-mi-yodeya), these levels will be reevaluated and adjusted, placing them on par with other graduated sites, so look for them to actually increase.

I've decreased the editing ability here on Meta to match the main site for now.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why it's designed this way, but the rep requirement to edit other people's posts on Main [is 500](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), while the corresponding requirement on Meta [is 1000](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: Anyone can suggest an edit, even anonymous & 1-rep users. The rep is the required rep before which a post can be edited without peer review

Comment: @Sathya I don't even see a suggested edit option!

Comment: @Naftali thanks for letting me know it was a bug, I have deleted my answer.