# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design, launch

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/design-for-mi-yodeya).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

[Main site favicon](http://sstatic.net/judaism/img/favicon.ico)

[Meta site favicon](http://sstatic.net/judaismmeta/img/favicon.ico)

We have also themed the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning), twitter account and email newsletter template for this site.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post here on Meta and tag it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: I am a huge fan of the quill icon for edited comments!

Comment: Jin, have you had a chance to look at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/hebrew-in-comments-and-sidebars-is-too-small-to-read ?

Comment: Jin, this is not an important or urgent issue, but I'm curious as to whether there is any plan for [a custom 404 or error page](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1018).

Comment: @msh210 yes, I haven't forgotten about it! Do you have any suggestions for 404?

Comment: Jin, there are a few as answers at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1018; the highest-voted seems to be http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1023. (If any use too much jargon, I'll be glad to translate/explain, as I'm sure others will be. Maybe comment on the jargony answer, or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468).)

Comment: Jin, do you plan on implementing styled [404 and error pages](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/why-were-we-left-with-boring-404-and-error-pages)?

Answer (score 6):

I really like how it puts Mi.Yodeya at the top of each page, in K'tav Rash"i.