# Can some out-of-date text on some help pages be fixed?

Tags: bug, help-center

On the help page for [Access Review Queues](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), there’s the following snippet:

> These and all other review queues are are accessible from the “review” link that appears at the top of every page next to your user name[...].

Since the menu bar has changed some time back, this description isn’t quite accurate, and for new users, a bit misleading as well. Go on, look at the top of the page - do you see a button that says “review” that’s next to your username? I don’t. What I do see is an icon of a checklist that’s next to my notification icons which are, in turn, next to my user icon. Since that’s the new home for review, shouldn’t the text on this page be updated so that it’s actually helpful in that regard?

A similar problem occurs on the [10K rep moderation tools](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) page. The snippet there reads:

> Access these tools by clicking the review link in the top bar, and then the Tools link in the header:
>
> [image: Picture of the above]

Now, I don’t exactly know where this link appears because I’m not quite at 10K just yet. What I do know is that it’s impossible for this picture to be accurate, because the review pages have the new top bar as well; there’s no review “word” link, only the “picture” link.

Can these pages be edited to accurately reflect the update to the site? Like I said before, for those who know where the review queue is, this doesn’t make such a big difference, but if you don’t know where it is, this could be really confusing.

Something to keep in mind is that I imagine once the [site format is fully updated](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4700/9682) more of these privileges pages will have to be changed. When (before, if possible) that happens, someone should probably skim through and make sure that nothing else falls out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the directions are that inaccurate. For the first example you mention, I don't think "review" necessarily means that there is a button that says "review". It means the review button. The checklist icon is the review button, and when you hold your mouse over it, it tells you as such:

[image]

Similarly, if the directions say to click on the Help Center button, it doesn't necessarily mean that there is a button made up of the words "Help Center". It means the question mark in a circle icon which tells you that it is the Help Center when you hover your mouse over it:

[image]

The second example is also pretty accurate. Once you open the review section that is indeed hat you see:

[image: w]

Comment: I stand corrected on the second one. The first one I think could be clarified a bit for new users, though. And it’s still not next to the user icon.

Comment: @DonielF You're not entirely incorrect on the second one. You only get to that image if you click on the review button and then click on either "all queues" or "tools".

Comment: @DonielF As for being next to the user icon, I think it just means that it's a button among the list of buttons next to your user icon, not necessarily that it is the very button next to the user icon.