# Can we link the Hebrew Mi Yodeya in the banner?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Currently the logo and the words mi yodeya in English in the banner serve as a link back to the home page. Clicking on the Hebrew does nothing. Would it be possible and/or advisable to link the Hebrew words to the home page as well?

Comment: I had been thinking of this for a while as well.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4755/9643