# Long question titles have words broken up by the 'Ask Question' button

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Notice that the word "violation" in the title of the question is split into two by the 'Ask Question' button.

[image]

I only just noticed this. Has it always been like this? Or is it something new?

Either way, seems like a bug to me.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318655/on-sites-with-new-responsive-theme-word-wrap-on-long-titles-breaks-in-the-middl

Comment: Well the Ask Question button itself is a recent development.

Comment: I think this is new in the last few days.  I noticed it once recently (it really jumped out) and I assumed a stray space in the title.  Then I saw it again and wondered.  Then I saw this meta post.  I'm saying all this because I *think* if this went all the way back to the rollout of the new design here, I would have noticed it earlier.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well the issue was noticed on (at least) five different sites all within the last day, so it's pretty likely it just came up.

Answer (score 8):

This should now be fixed in the next build. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Hi - would you be able to help us out with this as well? https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/can-we-link-the-hebrew-mi-yodeya-in-the-banner?noredirect=1&lq=1