# What does the Mi Yodeya tree represent?

Tags: discussion

What does the Mi Yodeya tree pictured on this site's banner represent?
Is there any Jewish symbolism involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/design-for-mi-yodeya)

> The logo is inspired by Tree of Life. Its branches subtly form the Star of David. The main branch and the "o" in "Yodeya" make up a question mark to reflect the Q&A nature of our site. The tittle in "Mi" is a falling leaf, which further bonds the logo mark and the logo type. The Hebrew letters of Mi Yodeya are embedded in the tree as hanging fruits.

Comment: Is the tree of life a jewish symbol? Does that refer to the eitz hadaat?

Comment: That’s the most common translation, yes.

Comment: @Shababnik I think Shmuel misread, eitz hachaim is the tree of life, not eitz hadaat.

Comment: The reference is to Proverbs 3:18 https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.3.18?lang=bi  עֵץ־חַיִּ֣ים הִ֭יא לַמַּחֲזִיקִ֣ים בָּ֑הּ וְֽתֹמְכֶ֥יהָ מְאֻשָּֽׁר, that wisdom (presumably Torah wisdom) is "a tree of life." Hence a gazillion synagogues and yeshivas named Etz Chayim or "Tree of Life."

Comment: @RabbiKaii yes, my apologies that is what I meant