# Why can't we use mi.yodeya.com?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Why can't we use `mi.yodeya.com` in the address bar? It still says J.SE even after the upgrade!

---

Related to this question on meta.so: [How does this SE site (beta) get custom domain & brand?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126261/155556)

---

Also related: [Where did all these posts come from?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/719)

Comment: @IsaacMoses -- why was this closed? Especially since we graduated!

Comment: I guess my thought was that it was overcome by events, since the logo does now say "mi yodeya." On further consideration, I've re-opened and tagged "status-completed."

Comment: @IsaacMoses it is **not** completed... the URL is still judaism.SE...

Comment: http://mi.yodeya.com goes to here just as it always did.

Comment: @IsaacMoses yes, but the URL in the address bar forwards to J.SE (which it shouldn't). it should stay at mi.yodeya!

Comment: @Naftali - So you're asking for a change that would require redirecting pretty much every URL here since the private beta? Seems easier to just leave it as it is.

Comment: @neilfein there is no real redirecting needed... just change the it should be seamless..

Comment: @msh210 -- please don't tag declined when  you are not the one that answered the question. It still could happen.

Comment: @Naftali, if Joel said no, then it's declined. I'll be glad to untag it and let an SE employee tag it if you insist.

Comment: (Actually, since it's not tagged [meta-tag:feature-request], I have no particular reason to think any SE employee will look at this again, and not being tagged with a "status" won't keep it 'open' to be looked at by them.)

Comment: @msh210 Joel did not seem to say **no**. I do not even see the word no anywhere in his answer...

Comment: @Naftali, that's probably because your question is worded "Why can't we...". So his answer is "The main reason... There are more minor technical reasons...". it seems like a clear No to me, though.

Comment: Naftali, If you want to argue about whether this *should* happen, I suggest you take it up with Joel in his answer. Regarding whether this *will* happen, I'd have to agree with @msh210 that unless and until the content of Joel's answer changes, which I would not expect to happen (and [am not advocating](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/site-rooms-link-goes-to-the-wrong-place#comment2930_1145)), the answer is unequivocally "no."

Comment: @Naftali I think his answer is pretty clear: _"...we really don't want to..."_

Answer (score 14):

The main reason has to do with "brand equity." We decided that when people see links to this site in Google, we want them showing up with the stackexchange.com URL, because they may have heard of Stack Exchange and know that it has a reputation for high quality answers => this translates to more traffic, more users, and ultimately better answers.

There are more minor technical reasons, such as the ability to share cookies with other network sites, the ability to do analytics (google analytics, quantcast, etc.) across the network, and the ability to have mi.yodeya traffic recognized as being a part of the Stack Exchange network in Alexa, Comscore, Quantcast, etc.

Askubuntu.com and answers.onstartups.com are legacy sites in which there is a legal agreement in place with a third party so they kept their top level domain name, but they create a world of complication that we really don't want to support for any future sites.