# "Jewish Life and Learning" in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-name, data-explorer

The [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/about) URLs still use the old name of the site, "Jewish Life and Learning", instead of the new one, "Mi Yodeya". E.g., [`http://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/queries`](http://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/queries).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The new URLs are [http://data.stackexchange.com/miyodeya/queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/miyodeya/queries) [http://data.stackexchange.com/miyodeyameta/queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/miyodeyameta/queries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that `jewish%20life%20and%20learning` should be scrubbed.

The convention we should follow would involve changing the slug to `judaism`, making it into `data.stackexchange.com/judaism/queries`, as Double AA suggested.

Comment: This is your only post here on Mi Yodeya...

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think it works on Meta. [Your options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245420/165581).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Consider our cousin "Seasoned Advice": their URL is `http://data.stackexchange.com/cooking/queries`.

This might change pending [this other request](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/951/759), but in the mean time, I think this issue and its resolution is very parallel to [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139/759).

Comment: You may be correct. But at least 'cooking' is the URL of the site. Also [cooking.se] is the official name of the site in various contexts: specifically, I made that link by typing `[cooking.se]`. Contrast `[judaism.se]` which makes [judaism.se].

Comment: @msh210 SeasonedAdvice is also the URL of the site, but it bounces to Cooking just like Mi.Yoedya bounces to Judaism.

Comment: Yes, not to Jewish Life and Learning. I *think* the Data Explorer is the only remnant of the old name JLL extant.

Comment: @msh210 Hmm if you make that chiluk you should really be asking that they change it to `/judaism/queries` not `/mi%20yodeya/queries`.