# "Site Rooms" link goes to the wrong place

Tags: bug, support, chat

I am in chat and I click on "site rooms":

[image: site rooms]

That directs me to:
`http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=judaism.stackexchange.com`
[image: j.se]

**BUT** if I try to change the URL to:
`http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=mi.yodeya.com`
It looks like this:
[image: mi.se]

It has the old *beta* design and **NO** chat rooms!

What is going on here???

Comment: So you invent a URL, type it in, and are surprised that you get strange results?

Comment: @balpha it still has the `mi.yodeya` logo and the like.

Comment: @balpha also the 2nd link should be the one going to the rooms since the name of the site changed.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't make any sense. If you just try random URLs, you can't have any expectation about the result. And I fail to see what the name of the site has to do with anything.

Comment: @balpha you cannot be serious. Why would the site name show up on the 2nd link? The official name for the site is `mi.yodeya` **not** `judaism.se`

Comment: @Naftali, this question seems to be predicated on [your other request](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/951/why-cant-we-use-mi-yodeya-com) being resolved the way you want, which it hasn't to date.

Comment: @IsaacMoses it **does not**. why would the 2nd URL even __SHOW__ the mi.yodeya logo if it was not associated with it at all?!

Comment: @Naftali, It probably has to do with the fact that that URL happens to redirect to J.SE. Try it with another URL that does that: miyodeya.com

Comment: @IsaacMoses nope: http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=miyodeya.com

Comment: @Naftali (Taking your word for it, as I can't access chat right now) Interesting. That would seem to imply that mi.yodeya.com is called out in chat's code, database, or settings somehow.

Comment: @Naftali the official **host** is judaism.SE - mi.yodeya.com is just a redirect. I will, however, see if I can get the alias code to at least make its mind up which styling to use

Comment: @Naftali for info, "miyodeya.com" is ***not*** listed in the official list of aliases for judaism.SE (see http://stackauth.com/sites, search for "Mi Yodeya") - which is why the image doesn't display on your own URL. If this is incorrect, let me know.

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed the issue with the UI being half-network-wide and half-site-specific (i.e. using the judaism images but the stackexchange background).

However! Your question is based on a false premise: as far as the system is concerned, the **host** for judaism is judaism.stackexchange.com; you might *refer* to it as mi.yodeya, but that **does not** make it the **host**. Chat is entirely correct to link to judaism.stackexchange.com, and not mi.yodeya.com (which exists only as a redirect).

Balpha is also correct to say that *if you invent your own urls* (based on nothing that the system has given you), then it is not unreasonable to expect odd results; however, the "half this and half that" offended my sense of correctness, *even for* an invalid URL.

If and when your [other request](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/why-cant-we-use-mi-yodeya-com) comes to pass, *then* we would re-point those rooms. Until then: chat is correct.

Comment: Do you know when my other request will come to fruition?

Comment: @Naftali I just write code ;p I'll ask...

Comment: kk cool, because since the offical name for this site now is Mi Yodeya, it would make sense to use the correct URL :-)

Comment: @Naftali now define "official name"... your *browser*, and the http stack - they all agree that, currently, "judaism.stackexchange.com" is the "official" point of reference. There's a difference between a *name* and a *host*.

Comment: Marc -- goto the site's creator [@IsaacMoses](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses) -- When this was a 1.0 site the official URL and name was mi.yodeya.com

Comment: @Naftali I have asked the question internally; I don't have the context to provide much of an answer myself.

Comment: @Naftali, The site belongs to SEI. I, for one, am content to have the name I like on the graphics and in various text locations, to have a redirect URL that reflects that name, and to leave the official host URL as the one that binds the site technically and semantically with the rest of the SE network.