# What kind of traffic is this site getting, and how does that compare to previous years?

Tags: discussion

I just started coming here in late December.  It seems to me that questions from a year ago got a lot more votes and comments than new questions are getting, even accounting for the longer period of time the older questions have been out there.  Is Mi Yodea less active relative to previous years?  If so, I wonder if it is because more of the basic questions have been taken and the newer questions tend to be at a pretty high level.

Comment: A bit of data for a snapshot in time: in the fall of 2011 we had a contest to promote the site; entrants claimed individual questions they found interesting and the one with the largest delta of views (plus some other stuff that I think was noise) won.  The delta for the winner was [295 views over 3 weeks](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/375/score-chart-and-final-results-for-the-ingathering-contest) and that was a freshly-asked question, so that doesn't seem all that high.  So the past had its slow times too. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your having joined the site (in December 2012), there have been no question now listed in top 200 votes questions (meaning no question has gotten more than 14 votes). [This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19036/1569) appears to be the latest one (15 votes).

Of the top 100 [greatest hits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), there have been none from 2013 (though it's only February, so that doesn't say anything). There have been 11 greatest hits since August 2012:

- [Why assume coffee is kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19088/1569)
- [Teachings of Chabad (Lubavitch) - controversial or not?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18785/1569)
- [Chassidic Rebbes don't use Hebrew Grammar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18529/1569)
- [What does Dovid Melech Yisrael Chai Vkayam mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22137/1569)
- [In Judaism, does God have a body?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20593/1569)
- [How can we be sure that Judaism is true/the truth?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18653/1569)
- [Can we play video games during sabbath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20451/1569)
- [Women and Mayim Acharonim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18749/1569)
- [How can God be just in light of Deuteronomy 23:3?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18375/1569)
- [Are "things we don't do because of danger" also dangerous to non-Jews?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22195/1569)
- [Nudity at home?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18216/1569)

Since January 1, 2013, we have had three 10+ votes questions (though there were quite a few in the 7-9 range):

- [Is unmasking an anonymous author addressed by Halacha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23296/1569)
- [Why did Avraham prefer the daughters of Aner, Eshkol and Mamre over Eliezer's daughter?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23375/1569)
- [What percentage of Chabad still believes their Rebbe is the Messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25946/1569)

In terms of users, we have 5 users on [this page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) who have not been seen since 2012 (plus one who hasn't been seen since January 1, 2013), according to the "last seen" section of the profile.

---

P.S.: [Surviving the zombie apocalypse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26237/1569) now ties this year's record. So I guess we can learn that Purim Torah is popular (so what's new?).

Answer (score 6):

If you look at [QuantCast's measurement](http://www.quantcast.com/judaism.stackexchange.com) of our traffic since mid-2011, when we [migrated](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) into the SE network, you'll see that:

- Both "people" and "visits" appear to have been generally trending upward, starting after the initial activity surrounding the migration dropped off.
- "Page views" seems to have been fairly flat since late 2011.

This seems to indicate less average activity on the site per user over time. I would guess that we're attracting more and more people for one-view visits via search, but our heavy use by community members has been about the same for the past year, or possibly declining a bit.