# Is there a way to track the number of votes?

Tags: discussion, votes

I have been wondering what the trend has been in voting -- not in upvotes or down votes, but total votes cast. I wonder if more recent questions have been getting as many votes (over a fixed period of time since their writing, and also in total even though they are younger) as questions posted in the past.

I looked at page 576 and noticed questions regularly with votes in the 15-20 range while I see those numbers less frequently on more recent pages -- is that a function of time or a change in voting habits, or a change in the overall quality of questions?

Comment: (It likely is a combination of factors which will be hard to separate by just looking at voting history graphs, but that's not really an answer to your question)

Comment: @DoubleAA I realized that as I was writing but I figured I would start with the effect and then worry about divining the causes later.

Comment: You can see the breakdown of votes over time for any individual question or answer by looking at the post's timeline. You could easily compare a couple of old posts with a couple of new posts, but it won't be practical on a large scale.

Comment: related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4932/170

Comment: @Alex Is it only available for the chosen ones?

Comment: @Kazibácsi Anyone can access it. You just have to replace the post title in the URL with "timeline", and change "questions" or "answers" to "posts". So for this post it would be https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5137/timeline