# The absense of the Beta Badge

Tags: discussion, badges

How come no one has the [Beta badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/16/beta) on this site?  There was no active participation in Beta?

Comment: Mi Yodeya was originally a SE 1.0 site and was migrated to SE 2.0. I assume that's the relevant factor here but I'll leave it for someone else to put it together.

Answer (score 7):

The badge text is "Actively participated in the private beta." Mi Yodeya never had a private beta phase. There was no need, since the point of a community's [private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63401/what-is-private-beta-status) is " a 'probationary' basis to see if people will use it," and Mi Yodeya (actually Judaism.Stackexchange then) [was founded](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) on the pre-existing mi.yodeya community from the Stackexchange 1.0 platform. The initial user base was already there, as was a body of questions, a community culture, and provisional moderators. It would have been silly to close the site that was open to the public and open one that would be initially restricted to people who had jumped through certain hoops on Area51.