# Who built/runs Mi Yodeya?

Tags: discussion

Who runs this site? Hillel is building a similar site for internal staff collaboration, and I would love to talk to someone about Mi Yodeya, and your user experience. 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. You should browse around a bit to get a feel for this site. As for this question (something for moderators, perhaps?) I think this should be moved to the meta area, so I vote to close for that reason.

Comment: Mind if I ask which college Hillel this is?

Comment: Is this the national Hillel or expected to be used by all the various Hillel's in every college? You would be welcome to join here as well in order to ask your questions. See the other stackexchange groups as well to get a feel for how it is set up.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

As indicated in comments<sup>1</sup> on this post, Mi Yodeya is a member of the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about) network of Q&A sites. It's provided and maintained by [Stack Overflow, Inc.](https://stackoverflow.com/company)<sup>2</sup>

The community generally regulates itself, [using tools](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) built into the platform. To handle special cases and expedite janitorial work, there is a small group of [elected moderators](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). You can see the list of moderators [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

[I'm](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses?tab=profile) one of the moderators, and I also founded the online community that [evolved into](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) the community here at Mi Yodeya. I love to talk about Mi Yodeya, and would be happy to talk to you. As it happens, I work very close to Hillel headquarters in DC, and I regularly visit that building for Mincha, so if you work there, it should be easy to arrange a meeting. You can contact me at lo_yodeya (or to be perfectly honest, any address) at isaacemoses.info.

---

<sup>1. Thanks [mbloch](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch) and [ezra](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11486/ezra).</sup>

<sup>2. For what it's worth, Stack Overflow is currently working on building a new feature called [Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/channels) that will allow private companies and teams to do technical Q&A using the Stack Exchange model, privately. I don't expect that this will be available and useful for non-technical teams for a long time.</sup>